# Combining equation numbering and multi-line equation alignment in Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word, latex, microsoft-word-2016, equations

Microsoft Word 2016 allows numbering equations with
LaTeX-style right-aligned equation numbers using the input
sequence `#(NUMBER)<Enter>`, producing output like

```
sed  diam nonumy  eirmod  tempor invidunt  ut labore  et
dolore magna aliquyam erat,

                   x = hello + world                (42)
                        y = foo                     (43)

sed diam voluptua.  At vero eos et accusam  et justo duo
dolores et ea  rebum. Stet clita kasd  gubergren, no sea
```

It also allows aligning equations by defining alignment
characters, e.g. by writing `&=` instead of `=`, resulting
in

```
sed  diam nonumy  eirmod  tempor invidunt  ut labore  et
dolore magna aliquyam erat,

                   x = hello + world
                   y = foo

sed diam voluptua.  At vero eos et accusam  et justo duo
dolores et ea  rebum. Stet clita kasd  gubergren, no sea
```

Is it somehow possible to combine the two features to
produce the equivalent of LaTeX's `align` environment? I.e.

```
sed  diam nonumy  eirmod  tempor invidunt  ut labore  et
dolore magna aliquyam erat,

                   x = hello + world                (42)
                   y = foo + bar                    (43)

sed diam voluptua.  At vero eos et accusam  et justo duo
dolores et ea  rebum. Stet clita kasd  gubergren, no sea
```

Comment: FWIW I tried a number of approaches and the basic problem seems to be that the #(number) feature only works properly for one number at the end of the equation. Everything I tried either broke the = alignment, failed to recognise one or more of the #(number) sequences properly, and so on. Another kludge I have tried is to avoid the #, use a phantom to insert extra space before the numbers in an eqarray, right-align the equation using the justification option on the dropdown, then adjust the width of the phantom manually to align the equation how you want. Horrible...

Comment: ...and there is still a problem because different equations do not appear to be right-aligned in quite the same way. But to try it, start with something like `\eqarray(x&=hello+world&\phantom(----------)&(42)@y&foo+bar&&(43))` . I couldn't always get the numbers to line up either - not sure why - even with another phantom in the second row - and tried using a `\matrix` instead, using the features to align columns. But then you tend to end up with too much space around the "=", for example.

Comment: @yokki It helps a lot already to know that the last equation of a series at least can be numbered.